# Proving set of linear functionals is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq 2}$ be the vector space of polynomials (with real coefficients) of degree at most $2$. Consider the functionals $l_1, l_2, l_3$ on this space: $$ l_1: f \mapsto \int_{0}^1 f(t) dt, \quad l_2: f \mapsto f'(1), \quad l_3: f \mapsto f(0). $$ I need to prove that $\mathcal{L} = \left\{l_1, l_2, l_3\right\}$ is a basis for the dual space $(\mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq 2} )^*$.

I need to prove linear independence and span. For the first, let $$ \lambda_1 l_1 + \lambda_2 l_2 + \lambda_3 l_3 = 0 $$ be a linear combination. I need to prove that all the $\lambda_i$ are zero. Let $f = a + bx + cx^2$ be some arbitrary polynomial. Then I evaluated both sides of the equation above with this polynomial to get $$ 0 = 0(f) = \lambda_1 (a + b/2 + c/3) + \lambda_2 (b+ 2c) + \lambda_3 a. $$ By solving the system of equations that arises for the coefficients and assuming that $a,b,c$ are not zero, I showed that each $\lambda_i$ must be zero. But I don't know how to prove the span. I need to show an arbitrary functional $l$ can be written as a combination of the base vectors. How can I do this?

**Edit:** I'm also interested in finding a basis $V = \left\{v_1, v_2, v_3\right\}$ for $\mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq 2}$ such that $V^* = \mathcal{L}$, i.e. such that $v_i^* = l_i$ for every $i$. Here $v_i^*$ means the projection on the $i$th coordinate, that is $$ v_i^*: \mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq 2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: f = \alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \alpha_3 v_3 \mapsto \alpha_i. $$

I'm not sure how such a basis $V$ looks like, and if it is unique. For the first basisvector $v_1$, and for an arbitrary polynomial $f \in \mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq 2}$ we would need $$v_1^* (f) = l_1(f) = \int_0^1 f(t) dt. $$

Comment: Well, you have linear independence, now, for linear span, it is enough to consider the dimension of the space.

Comment: Solving this problem may help you solve your problem: Show that for any linear map $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ there exist $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y,z) = ax + by + cz$. Notice that this is just the inner product of $(a,b,c)$ and $(x,y,z)$. If you figure that out, recall that $\mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq 2}$ is a 3-dimensional vector space, so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$. See if you can formulate your solution using the standard inner product in $\mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq 2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V = \mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq 2}$. You want to show that for an arbitrary $\phi \in V^*$, there exist scalars $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ such that

$$ 
\phi = \alpha_1 l_1 + \alpha_2 l_2 + \alpha_3 l_3,
$$

meaning that for every $p(x) = a + bx + cx^2 \in V$,

$$
\phi (p(x)) = \phi ( a + bx + cx^2) = \alpha_1 l_1(a + bx + cx^2) + \alpha_2 l_2(a + bx + cx^2) + \alpha_3 l_3(a + bx + cx^2),
$$

which, as you have already computed is equal to

$$
\alpha_1 (a + \frac b2 + \frac c3) + \alpha_2(b + 2c) + \alpha_3 a.
$$

If we can find a basis $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ for $V$ such that

$$
p(x) = a + bx + cx^2 = (a + \frac b2 + \frac c3)v_1 + (b + 2c)v_2 + a v_3,
$$

then by linearity of $\phi$, we would have

$$
\phi(p(x)) = (a + \frac b2 + \frac c3)\phi(v_1) + (b + 2c)\phi(v_2) + a \phi(v_3),
$$

and by setting $\alpha_1 = \phi(v_1)$, $\alpha_2 = \phi(v_2)$, and $\alpha_3 = \phi(v_3)$ we would be done.

Take $v_1 = 3x - \frac32 x^2, v_2 = -\frac 12x + \frac 34 x^2,$ and $v_3 = 1 - 3x + \frac 32 x^2$. You can check that these three polynomials form the desired basis.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the proof for independence goes slightly differently: your plugging in of the arbitrary polynomial indeed shows that

$$0 = \lambda_1(a+\frac{b}{2} + \frac{c}{3}) + \lambda_2(b + 2c) + \lambda_3 a$$

for *all* choices of $a,b,c$, because the equality (of functionals) $\lambda_1 l_1 + \lambda_2 l_2 + \lambda_3 l_3 = 0$ must hold for all points of the space (i.e. all polynomials). So then you *choose* convenient $a,b,c$ to show that $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 0$.

Furthermore, $1,X,X^2$ is clearly a base for $\mathbb{R}[X]_{\le 2}$, so its dimension is 3. So if you have a linearly independent set of size 3 in this space, it must be spanning the whole space, by standard theorems.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I edited my post at the bottom, because I have another question now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $[L]_{ij} = l_i(x \mapsto x^{j-1})$ for $i,j = 1,2,3$.
A tedious computation shows that $L$ is invertible.

Now choose a functional $\phi$, note that the behaviour of $\phi$ is
completely determined by the numbers $b_i = \phi(x \mapsto x^{i-1})$. Let
$\alpha$ solve $L \alpha = b$, then
$(\sum_k \alpha_k l_k )(x \mapsto x^{j-1}) = [L \alpha]_j = b_j = \phi(x \mapsto x^{i-1})$ and so $\phi = \sum_k \alpha_k l_k$. Hence the $l_k$
span the dual space.

For the second part (and with awkward notation), let $\alpha^k$ solve $L \alpha^k = e_k$, where $e_k$ is the $k$th standard unit vector.
Let $v_i = \sum_k  \alpha^k (x \mapsto x^{k-1})$ (that is, the polynomial
$v_i(x) = \sum_k  \alpha^k x^{k-1}$). Then, as above, we see that
$l_i(v_j) = \delta_{ij}$.

It follows that the basis $v_k$ is unique, since if $l_i(v) =l_i(w)$ for all $i$ then $v=w$.

Comment: Why the downvote?